# How can I prevent Vim from exiting visual mode?

Tags: visual-mode

If I enter visual mode, select some text, then run a command or press a keybinding, it will exit visual mode afterward because it assumes I am done.

But sometimes I want to do multiple things with that visual selection.

How can I make Vim stay in visual mode unless I explicitly exit by pressing `Escape`?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4711079/11135136.
Which was itself a duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/115038/1014071.
But those are both from outside of vi.stackexchange, so the question can't be closed.

Comment: I searched for it online before posting and it is strange that I did not find those prior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no in built vim option to leave it selected.

However but there is a way to reselect quickly

- You can use `gv` to reselect the last selection.
- Or can use `|` to put multiple commands (For more information https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Multiple_commands_at_once)

If it's indent related then these mappings might be useful

```
local map = vim.api.nvim_set_keymap
map('v', '<', '<gv', (noremap=true, silent=true))
map('v', '>', '>gv', (noremap=true, silent=true))
```

Comment: Same answer was given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4711096/11135136. (It also has a slightly better approach (using `.`) for indenting usage.)

Comment: Thanks, I will fork Neovim and submit a pull request for an option to keep visual mode selected.